# Уникальные пары чисел

Tags: алгоритм, php

Есть двумерный массив чисел:

```
$TEXTURE = array(
    1 => array(1, 2),
    3 => array(2, 5, 6, 7),
);
```

Также дается массив пар чисел:

```
A = ( (1,1), (1,2), (1,1), (3,2) )
```

Необходимо вернуть массив пар такой, чтобы числа в нем не повторялись, т.е. по примеру (1,1) повторяется, вместо нее можно поставить (3,5)

В голову приходит только перебор в лоб:

1. создаем новый массив пар R
2. в цикле по массиву A перебираем пары
3. проверяем есть ли данная пара в R / опять же в цикле / если нет, то добавляем
4. если есть, то ищем следующее число по массиву $TEXTURE, с начало по вложенному массиву, потом переходим к следующему, таких, чтобы этой пары не было в R

**Есть ли более интересное решение данной задачи?**

---

**Добавлено**

В общем, суть проблемы: есть набор текстур, которые я идентифицирую по 2 числам, например (2,2). На отображение пойдет N объектов, которые имеют свои текстуры (все N текстур записаны в массиве A). Необходимо Все дублирующие текстуры заменить на неиспользуемые.

Comment: 1. Повторение имеется ввиду (2,2) (3,3) или (5,1) и (5,1) ?  
1.1. Является ли (1,5) и (5,1) повторением ?  
2. Почему нужно именно (3,5) подставить ?  
Дайте четкую формулировку задачи, мне кажется, что это просто вольный пересказ.

Comment: @ReinRaus В общем, суть проблемы: есть набор текстур, которые я идентифицирую по 2 числам, например (2,2). На отображение пойдет N объектов, которые имеют свои текстуры (все N текстур записаны в массиве A). Необходимо Все дублирующие текстуры заменить на неиспользуемые.

1. Повторение имеется в виду (5,1) и (5,1)

  1.1 (1,5) и (5,1) не является повторением

2. Можно любой из свободных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать хэш-таблицу по парам (i, j). Таким образом проверка на то, что элемент уже встречался, будет быстрой.

Чтобы подставлять отсутствующие пары, возможно, придётся сделать дополнительный проход чтобы сначала понять, какие пары уже есть.

А вообще, задача выглядит слишком размытой и простой. Напишите, например, какое бывает N, какие i и j...

Comment: N обычно от 2 до 4. i,j - любые

Comment: От 2-х до 4-х текстур в списке А?! Тогда только тупой поиск!

Comment: поступил хитрее )) завел список текстур, которые гарантировано не используются, и вместо поиска очередного неиспользуемого беру по-очереди из этого списка